# JBoss JMX Console and Web Console Vulnerabilities

Tags: security, jboss, redhat, jmx

My friend needs help in solving this issues,the server is being installed with **J Boss version 4.2** :-

> 1. Red Hat JBoss Application Server Web Console and JMX Management Console Authentication Bypass Vulnerability
> 2. JBoss HttpAdaptor JMXInvokerServlet is Accessible to Unauthenticated Remote Users
> 3. Red Hat JBoss EJBInvokerServlet is Accessible to Unauthenticated Remote Users
> 4. JBoss JMX Console and Web Console Unrestricted Access Vulnerability
> 5. JBoss JMX Console is Accessible to Unauthenticated Remote Users
> 6. JBoss Web Console is Accessible to Unauthenticated Remote Users

We tried a lot but still not able to fix it. we changed the admin password, uncommented the security block and commented the GET and POST method.

Can you please tell us the path also where all we need to change. so that if we have missed anything we can correct it .

Comment: Take a look in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SECURITY-31 and https://access.redhat.com/solutions/30744